# Python - plot legend of classified datapoints with different colors using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I spent a lot of time trying to find a solution for my stupid problem but I didn't manage to do it. I'm a newbie in Python (and in plotting above all).

What I would like to do is to plot a small legend for my datapoint. I have a 2-dimensional dataset with a class [0,1,2] for each entry. This is the code I wrote for plotting my dataset:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.scatter(reduced_dataset[:,0], reduced_dataset[:,1], c=y.Gender)
plt.xlabel('PC 1')
plt.ylabel('PC 2') 
plt.legend()
plt.figure()
```

And this is my output image:
[image]

So, what I want is first of all to know which class the three colours represent and to add a small legend on the top right explaining this.

Edit: I add some details. 
My dataset, called *reduced_dataset* is a 2-dimensional dataset like this, obtained from a 8-dimensional dataset by the application of PCA (n_components=2):

```
[[5.29251,-0.680271]
[-10.6902,0.135495]
[-0.676506,-0.0493725]
[0.306184,-0.315342]
[-2.73479,-0.705164]]
```

and I have a vector that represents the classes for each row of my dataset:

```
[0,0,1,0,2]
```

So the class could be 1, 2 or 3, that's why I have three color for the datapoints in my plot. I would need a legend like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some sample data if you want a full answer.

Comment: Specifically a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry. I edited the message with more informations.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the plot static, then plot each data series in sequence the legend will be created automatically:

```
import itertools

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlabel('PC 1')
ax.set_ylabel('PC 2')
marker = itertools.cycle(('o', '^', 's', 'x', '*'))

# Get the method name, and its measurements for all datasets
for method, measurements in method_metric_dict.items():
    # Get the measurements for the requested data, and calc their stats
    # Plot the line for the method and dataset
    ax.scatter(measurements[:,0], measurements[:,1], label=method, marker=next(marker))
plt.legend()
```